# Como fazer aplicação angular funcionar apenas em um navegador específico?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end

Gostaria de fazer minha aplicação angular funcionar em um determinado navegador, e bloquear qualquer outra versão.

Ex: Funcionar apenas no Google Chrome 75. E se o usuário tentar acessar em um Firefox, Edge, ou Chrome em qualquer versão posterior ou inferior, ele envia um mensagem ao usuário que esta tentando usar esta aplicação.

Comment: qual versão do Angular?

Comment: Seria a versão 8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade: "navigator.userAgent" para exibir a versão do browser. Existem outras propriedades também. Execute o código abaixo em um navegador para visualizar todas elas:

```
var txt = "";
txt += "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt += "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
alert(txt);
```

Comment: Esse funcionou... mas eu teria que usar um algoritmo para pegar o valor de dentro da string, certo? A string seria esta: "5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Não basta `console.log(navigator.appVersion.includes("Chrome/75"));` ? Talvez não funcione para todos os casos mas certamente apanhará a maioria.